# Meteor Exception in template helper

Tags: javascript, meteor, geojson

I have a problem with in my application, I get an error on this line

```
<pre><code>type: 'Point'</code></pre>
```

Error:

```
Exception in template helper
```

The structure in Locs is a **GeoJSON** structure.

This is the code on client side:

```
nextlocation: function(){
      var geodata = Geolocation.latLng();
      var nextloc = Locs.find({
        location: {
          $near: {
            $geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [geodata.lng,geodata.lat]
            },
            $maxDistance: 100000
          }
        }
      });
      console.log(nextloc);
      return nextloc;
    }
```

The code in the template:

```
{{nextlocation._id}}
```

I have no idea why there is an error.

Comment: Wrap your helper with `try{ ... } catche(e){ console.error(e) }` and see what error you receive

Comment: I'm sure the error is much more than `Exception in template helper` and should include the file name and line number which in turn show you the exact code that causes a problem. If you could share that information, we could then probably be able to help you.